# I can't reach interaktingslider in Magento

Tags: upgrade, 404, magento-connect-manager

I try to help out a friend with his webshop and like to add an image to the interaktingslider ( with hyperlink to a page on the webshop). It looks like the interaktionslidertab edittab,or add new slidetab are not active. Clicking those 3 tabs they give a page not found 404.

I'd like to update the whole slider through magento connect manager. Hoping we can reach the slider like this way.
But also this magentoconnect manager page gives this note:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /downloader/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somename.nl%2Findex.php%2Fsomenameadmin%2F on this server. www.somename.nl

What could be wrong. It's the webshop of a friend of mine..we've both the adminstrator role.

Magento version is 1.9.2.2
And..i don't have acces to the files yet..so no cpanel available for me.

The developer doesn't do magento websites anymore and is not very willing to help.

I hope for some answers how to reach the slider again.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This extension hasn't been updated since 2013 and has been taken offline by the developer himself. You can view his profile [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/Interakting.com). I suggest you find another extension.